# Google fonts family. Reference specific font face by class. How?

Tags: html, css

**Take for example the following font:**

[Roboto Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono)

According to the page, it comes with many type faces to choose from.

**I import it like this:**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

**I create the CSS classes:**

```
/*
Custom Class  : FONT-ROBOTO-MONO[-*]
Override      : N/A
Method        : N/A
Usage Example : <p class="font-roboto-mono-bold"></p>
*/

.font-roboto-mono { font-family: Roboto Mono, monospace; }

.font-roboto-mono-thin { font-family: Roboto Mono Thin, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-thin-italic { font-family: Roboto Mono Thin Italic, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-light { font-family: Roboto Mono Light, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-light-italic { font-family: Roboto Mono Light Italic, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-regular { font-family: Roboto Mono Regular, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-regular-italic { font-family: Roboto Mono Regular Italic, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-medium { font-family: Roboto Mono Medium, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-medium-italic { font-family: Roboto Mono Medium Italic, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-bold { font-family: Roboto Mono Bold, monospace; }
.font-roboto-mono-medium-bold { font-family: Roboto Mono Bold Italic, monospace; }
```

**I use it like this:**

```
<p class="font-roboto-mono-bold">Hello world!</p>
```

...and nothing changes. I suspect I am missing a parameter in the import URL. I cannot seem to find online if I need to import each one separately or just add them to the URL import.

For the record, **Roboto Mono** class is the only one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
  font-family: 'Rotobo Mono';
  font-size: 20pt;
}

.thin{
  font-weight: 100;
}
.light{
  font-weight: 300;
}

.regular{
  font-weight: 400;
}
.medium{
  font-weight: 500;
}
.bold{
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

<p class="thin">Thin</p>
<p class="light">Light</p>
<p class="regular">Regular</p>
<p class="medium">Medium</p>
<p class="bold">Bold</p>
```

If you want to change font's style, you should use `font-weight`

Comment: @ASPiRE I think, I was wrong. I will edit my answer.

Comment: As for the URL import parameters... since you are doing the styling in pure CSS, does it still need to possess `100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i`?

Answer (score 1):

**Final Revision**

```
/*
Custom Class  : FONT-ROBOTO-MONO + FONT-WEIGHT-[-*]
Override      : N/A
Import        : <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
Usage Example : <p class="font-roboto-mono font-weight-thin"></p>
*/

/* Initialize */
.font-roboto-mono {
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

/* Call */
.font-weight-thin {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

.font-weight-thin-italic {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}

.font-weight-light {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.font-weight-light-italic {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}

.font-weight-regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.font-weight-regular-italic {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

.font-weight-medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.font-weight-medium-italic {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
}

.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.font-weight-bold-italic {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
```